# remove sample data from excel template

Tags: excel, excel-template

I have downloaded an 2013 Excel template from a search within Excel titled "Sales Invoice Tracker"  The workbook is protected so I can look into the actual tables and just delete the records.

It has been set up with sample data and I can't find a way to delete/remove all existing data and begin with my own. I've not  worked with a template  before - Seems like I've missed a setup option!

Answer (score 0):

You can just remove the data on the `Invoices - Main` and `Invoices - Details` sheets. Then add your own data.

To customise the `Invoice` sheet, follow the instructions in the section `How do I get started?` on the `About This Invoice Tracker` sheet. It involves unprotecting the sheet (you should re-protect it after changing the Invoice since all the data comes from the other sheets).

Comment: Yes - I have gone over the how-to sections MANY times and finding woefully inadequate inadequate or, hopefully I’ve missed something.

Comment: Yes - I have gone over the how-to sections MANY times and finding woefully inadequate inadequate or, hopefully I’ve missed something. I have taken each sheet of sample data and Cleared content - but it always comes back. At one point the Invoice stopped totaling each entry! What I need are some clear (unlike the how-to section) help on how to get all that data properly removed. I’ve cleared data and saves it  as aa template- still no joy!

Comment: It comes as a template but you save it as a normal workbook (xlsx). Also, to delete the data, select multiple cells in the first column, right-click and choose Delete -> Table Rows. It will remove the rows from the table.